# if I reinstall the same system, it remains the same?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have problems with my system, and I haven't found any solution to them. To solve them, I decided to reinstall the same system, there's an option that says something like "install the system but saving the documents" can I trust it? Will everything stay the same? Help.

Comment: It would help a great deal if you let us know what the problems are. That way, we may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Conclusion: It is safe, but you ALWAYS should back up anyway.